# Reading database table into a .NET object of different structure

Tags: .net, database, object

I have inflation rates stored in a database with the following structure:

[image: Database schema and sample data]

When reading the above data, I need to initialize business objects with a different structure dynamically and fill them with the database data.

If the database would be like the above, I would need to create two objects: "UK Inflation Forecast" and "Germany Inflation Forecast". In this case, both objects would have 6 properties: CountryName (as String) and 5 inflation values (as Double).

[image: Business objects]

How can I create the object classes without knowing the number of properties needed and how do I fill these with data?

Comment: You know the number of properties/fields in the class: they are two! The country name and the collection of inflation data. The collection can be a `List<decimal>` if there are no gaps in the sequence and you know the start year. Otherwise you could store in in a `Dictionary<int, decimal>` which maps the year to the rate for that year. Note I recommend `decimal` over double for values such as these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say create a class of the following structur:

```
public class InflationClass
{
    public InflationClass()
    {
        InflationValues = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    }

    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, double> InflationValues { get; private set; }
}
```

And load the data like so

```
int sampleYear = 2016;
double sampleValue = 123456789.01;

var inflation = new InflationClass();

if(!inflation.InflationValues.ContainsKey(sampleYear ))
{
    inflation.InflationValues.Add(sampleYear , sampleValue);
}
```

I've used C# but this can easily be converted to VB.NET if you prefer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I can use just List here since I always know the starting year and there are no gaps in values. How would I effectively fill the data from the example database? I have ORM which helps me querying the database table. How do I get the data on to this new InflationClass object? LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

@user2143213 you can use linq or ADO.NET data reader.